# Postfix vs Crontab

Tags: email, cron, centos

I have a CentOS server and I found a script which sends me emails about the health status of the machine. Postfix is correctly configured as the script does his job and I receive my reports into my gmail account, however when I request a cron job in /etc/crontab to send me this report once a day at 11pm the next morning I receive 120 emails!

The first one is the report I have requested, the second one is like the following :

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
>    root@server.localdomain
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure:
>      DNS Error: Address resolution of server.localdomain. failed: Domain name not found

120 emails which are 60 reports and other 60 the above error message.

Again, if I run the script right now it works fine, I receive 1 email with my report and no failure delivery.

Is anything to do with cron ? the line `/etc/crontab` is the following :

```
* 23 * * * root sh /home/fr2632v2/Downloads/linuxhealthcheck.sh
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cron is trying to send email to `root` email address which by default is `root@hostname`. You have two options.

1. Configure global `root` email in `/etc/aliases`.

   - below `# Person who should get root's mail`
   - add `root: your@email.com`
2. Configure cron to send reports to a specific address

   - Edit `/etc/crontab` and change `MAILTO=` to a desired email address.

Now that you have it configured you should receive 2 emails: 1 from script itself (as you mentioned you revceive one even if you run it manually) and 2 from cron STDOUT (normal output) of the job. If you dont wish to receive the the second one change your cronjob to following: (it will still send an email in case of an error):

```
* 23 * * * root sh /home/fr2632v2/Downloads/linuxhealthcheck.sh > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I followed your steps and I dont receive the failed email anymore, however still 120 emails. 60 are my report and 60 are just like : Reported file health-server-150801-2357.txt generated in current directory.

Comment: Your current cronjob is set to run every minute of 23rd hour (23:00, 23:01, etc) 
To have it run once a day change it to `0 23 * * * root sh /home/fr2632v2/Downloads/linuxhealthcheck.sh > /dev/null`

Comment: That was the 'issue' ! Thank you!!